# How to use fresco in recyclerview to gain best performance?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-recyclerview, fresco

I have a recyclerview that has many images and I used fresco to load images.
but when I use the placeholder for images, my recyclerview slows down and lags.
I set a placeholder for the image in XML layout. I try that at code too and I have a problem yet.
I used below code in my xml layout:

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView 
android:id = "@+id/my_image_view"
android:layout_width = "24dp"
android:layout_height = "24dp"
fresco:placeholderImage = "@drawable/my_placeholder" />
```

How to improve my recyclerview performance? Thanks.

Comment: You can try on code, but init the Bitmap/Drawable only once (in the constructor best) and set the same one in all views. Or load the placeholder async also.

Comment: I do all you said but recyclerview slows down yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is create hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi resource folder at drawable for placeholder based on each device and use fresco resizing and downsampling on SimpleDraweeView. I do that and got best performance without any memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

Fresco has a RecyclerView sample here: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/showcase/src/main/java/com/facebook/fresco/samples/showcase/drawee/DraweeRecyclerViewFragment.java

You can clone the repo and build the Showcase app yourself if you want to play around with it.
Is your placeholder a simple PNG asset? How big is the placeholder image and how big are your normal images? If you try to load large images, make sure to enable downsampling / resizing for the images, see http://frescolib.org/docs/resizing.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw fresco sample but did not help me. My placeholder is a simple PNG. I enable downsampling and resizing for the images according to fresco docs but that not work to me.